# Angular 2 App from Quickstart to production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, gruntjs

I have started an Angular2 project from quickstart. What I need to be able to do is ensure that I only have the necessary files stored on my live server. I'm not quite sure what's needed and what's not using the quickstart repo.

Comment: From [this quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)? See https://github.com/angular/quickstart#delete-non-essential-files-optional.

Answer (score 0):

you should use build.

build will creating the folder 'dist' on your project.

the 'dist' folder should running as a static folder in your server.

for example on node.js server with express.js you need:

1) copy dist to your nodejs project.

2) make 'dist' folder static by:

```
var app = express(); 
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```